# str = str + "abc" slower than str = "abc" + str?

Tags: swift, string, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Can you believe it?
I have a loop like this (forgive any errors, I had to heavily redact a lot of info and variable names, trust me it works).

...Old example edited out, see below code...

And if I change those middle `str = "Blah \(odat.count)" + str` type lines to `str = str + "Blah \(odat.count)"` the UI grinds to a halt and I get colour wheel. The NSTextField does get to the first `self.display.string...` but then freezes.

I'm a multithreading novice so please feel free to correct my method. Hopefully it's clear what I want.

I have to admit the working version is also a little stuttery but never actually freezes.
Typical values are n = 70, var3 = 7.

EDIT:

Here is a fully working example. Just link up the textview, progress bar, and button(s). Try changing between the main functions.

```
//
//  Controllers.swift
//
//

import Cocoa

class MainController: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet var display: NSTextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var prog: NSProgressIndicator!

    @IBAction func go1(sender: AnyObject) {
        theRoutine(70)
    }

    @IBAction func go2(sender: AnyObject) {
        theRoutine(50)
    }

    class SomeClass {
        var x: Int
        var y: Int
        var p: Double

        init?(size: Int, pro: Double) {
            x = size
            y = size
            p = pro
        }
    }

    func theRoutine(n: Int) {
        prog.hidden = false
        prog.doubleValue = 0
        prog.maxValue = 7 * 40
        let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            self.theFunc(n, var1: 0.06, var2: 0.06, var3: 7)
            self.theFunc(n, var1: 0.1*log(Double(n))/Double(n), var2: 0.3*log(Double(n))/Double(n), var3: 7)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.prog.hidden = true
                self.appOut("done!")
            }
        }
    }

    //This doesn't
//  func theFunc(n: Int, var1: Double, var2: Double, var3: Int) {
//      var m: AnEnum
//      var gra: SomeClass
//      var p = var1
//      for _ in 0...(var3 - 1) {
//          var str  = "blah \(p)\n"
//          for _ in 1...20 {
//              gra = SomeClass(size: n, pro: p)!
//              m = self.doSomething(gra)
//              switch m {
//              case .First(let dat):
//                  str = str + "Blah:\n\(self.arrayF(dat, transform: {"blah\($0)blah\($1)=blah"}))" + "\n\n" + str
//              case .Second(let odat):
//                  str = str + "Blah\(odat.count) blah\(self.arrayF(odat, transform: {"bl\($1)"}))" + "\n\n" + str
//              }
//              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
//                  self.prog.incrementBy(1)
//              }
//          }
//          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
//              // update some UI
//              self.display.string = str + "\n" + (self.display.string ?? "")
//          }
//          p += var2
//      }
//  }

    //This works
    func theFunc(n: Int, var1: Double, var2: Double, var3: Int) {
        var m: AnEnum
        var gra: SomeClass
        var p = var1
        for _ in 0...(var3 - 1) {
            var str  = "blah \(p)\n"
            for _ in 1...20 {
                gra = SomeClass(size: n, pro: p)!
                m = self.doSomething(gra)
                switch m {
                case .First(let dat):
                    str = "Blah:\n\(self.arrayF(dat, transform: {"blah\($0)blah\($1)=blah"}))" + "\n\n" + str
                case .Second(let odat):
                    str = "Blah\(odat.count) blah\(self.arrayF(odat, transform: {"bl\($1)"}))" + "\n\n" + str
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.prog.incrementBy(1)
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // update some UI
                self.display.string = str + "\n" + (self.display.string ?? "")
            }
            p += var2
        }
    }

    func doSomething(G: SomeClass) -> AnEnum {
        usleep(30000)
        if drand48() <= G.p {
            return AnEnum.First([0, 0])
        } else {
            return AnEnum.Second([1, 1, 1])
        }
    }

    enum AnEnum {
        case First([Int])
        case Second([Int])
    }

    func appOut(out: String?) {
        if out != nil {
            display.string = out! + "\n\n" + (display.string ?? "")
        }
    }

    func arrayF(array: [Int], transform: (index: Int, value: Int) -> String) -> String {
        let arr = Array(0...(array.count - 1))
        return "[\(arr.map{transform(index: $0, value: array[$0])}.joinWithSeparator(", "))]"
    }
}
```

Comment: if those lines of code are on a background thread, then your UI would not freeze,  unless you are writing and reading to `str`,  at the same time.  I believe that is where your problem lies, do not dispatch `self.display.string = str + "\n" + (self.display.string ?? "")` until you know `str` is finiished.  This is where atomic came in handy in objective c

Comment: Of course we trust you that it works. But in order to investigate your problem, a *self-contained* example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: there is also something I seem to me missing,  what actually calls theFunc?

Comment: This is pure speculation (since we can't reproduce your example, as @MartinR mentions above), but it's possible that the Swift compiler is (too?) clever and treats `str = str + "Blah \(odat.count)"` as `str += "Blah \(odat.count)". In the latter `str` is an `inout` variable mutated in the operation (however with copy in copy out behavior ...), which has some subtle differences compared to the `+` operator, which use return of the operator call to overwrite/mutate `str`. Possibly claiming `str` as an inout variable has some effect on race conditions to `str`.

Comment: I have a working example everyone! Hooray! See the next post/edit.

Comment: i.e. a self contained example @MartinR comment if you have any questions about implementing this.

Comment: here is self-contained example https://gist.github.com/ojosdegris/df72a94327d12a67fe65e5989f9dcc53

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not really asking a question other than

> Can you believe it?

I will tell you that I surely can, but seriously there are a lot of cases when prepending something may be slower/faster than appending. Take for instance linked list. Prepend is O(1) and Append is O(N) if you are not holding reference to the last element of the list.

I put together gist that just times that particular issue , and on 5-6 runs it does not seem to be significant difference , however prepend is still 10% slower on my machine.

What is interesting you basically have 4 ways of concatenating strings in Swift regarding your case:

- prepend to accumulator  `str  = newstr + str`
- append to accumulator `str = str + newstr`
- append-mutate `str.append(newstr)`
- use good-old array as a string buffer and join it all at once `a = []; a.append(x); str = a.joined(separator: " ")`

On my machine they seems to all deviate around pretty much the same time with typical timing like this:

```
prepend
real    0m0.082s
user    0m0.060s
sys 0m0.018s

append
real    0m0.070s
user    0m0.049s
sys 0m0.018s

append mutate
real    0m0.075s
user    0m0.054s
sys 0m0.019s

join
real    0m0.086s
user    0m0.064s
sys 0m0.020s
```

Append being fastest.

You can see code for all four cases in my gist 
https://gist.github.com/ojosdegris/df72a94327d12a67fe65e5989f9dcc53

If you check out Swift sources on Github, you'll see this:

```
@effects(readonly)
@_semantics("string.concat")
public static func + (lhs: String, rhs: String) -> String {
 if lhs.isEmpty {
  return rhs
 }
 var lhs = lhs
 lhs._core.append(rhs._core)
 return lhs
}
```

So what is probably happening as accumulator string grows it is more expensive to copy it.

Comment: I did my own experiments in XCTests since seeing that the simple loops demonstrate this. I found that increasing the loop size by orders of magnitude shows much bigger differences between the two. Switching to append wasn't much better.

Answer (score 1):

Vittore's answer is correct. Looking at Swift's source code for String ([stdlib/public/core/String.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift)), we can see:

> Although strings in Swift have value semantics, strings use a copy-on-write
>   strategy to store their data in a buffer. This buffer can then be shared
>   by different copies of a string. A string's data is only copied lazily,
>   upon mutation, when more than one string instance is using the same
>   buffer. Therefore, the first in any sequence of mutating operations may
>   cost O(*n*) time and space.
>
> When a string's contiguous storage fills up, a new buffer must be allocated
>   and data must be moved to the new storage. String buffers use an
>   exponential growth strategy that makes appending to a string a constant
>   time operation when averaged over many append operations.

Per Wikipedia's [Copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write):

> If a resource is duplicated but not modified, it is not necessary to create a new resource; the resource can be shared between the copy and the original.

With this in mind, when doing `str = str + "abc"`, the compiler is performing a shallow copy of `str` and appending `"abc"` to its contiguous memory. On the other hand, `str = "abc" + str` creates an independent instance with its own unique copy of data since it isn't using contiguous memory anymore.

Comment: Thank you. I have awarded the correct answer to @Vittore (thank you!!) but you gave the important Swift detail with source so have awarded the bounty to you.